# apache camel crypto set 'CamelSignaturePublicKeyOrCert' in JMS TextMessage Header

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am trying to sign the payload of a JMS text message with a private key. The message is then sent to a queue and routed accordingly. The signature will be place in the message header along with the public key.

I am using the following code to set the header with the public key.

```
TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
String publicKey = new String(pubk.getEncoded());
 textMessage.setStringProperty("CamelSignaturePublicKeyOrCert", publicKey);
```

However when the message is begin routed I get the following error

*11:13:20,027 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener] Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot verify signature as no Public Key or Certificate has been supplied. Either supply one in the route definition or via the message header 'CamelSignaturePublicKeyOrCert']: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot verify signature as no Public Key or Certificate has been supplied. Either supply one in the route definition or via the message header 'CamelSignaturePublicKeyOrCert*

the routes are defined as follows

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<!-- Dependencies: ojdbc.jar and aqjms.jar must be in the activemq lib directory -->
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:queue.outbound"/>
    <log message="The expected queue is :: ${headers.queue}" />

     <to uri="crypto:verify://slpy" />
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${headers.queue} == 'ora'</simple>
            <to uri="oracleQueue:queue:SLEEPY_LION_QUEUE"/>
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${headers.queue} == 'proc'</simple>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:queue.proc"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="Invalid queue"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue I updated the broker-config.xml as follows

```
<route>
    <!-- <package>com.rs2.sleepylion.routes</package> -->
    <from uri="activemq:queue:queue.outbound"/>

    <to uri="log:in?showHeaders=true" />
    <log message="The expected queue is :: ${headers.queue}" />
    <to uri="log:out?showHeaders=true" />

    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${headers.queue} == 'ora'</simple>
            <to uri="oracleQueue:queue:SLEEPY_LION_QUEUE"/>
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${headers.queue} == 'proc'</simple>
            <to uri="crypto:verify://headers?publicKey=#myPublicKey&amp;clearHeaders=false" />
            <to uri="activemq:queue:queue.proc"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="Invalid queue"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
<bean id="myPublicKey" class="com.rs2.sleepylion.routes.Keys" factory-method="publicKey"/>
```